# Can we ask what Key a piece is in?

Tags: discussion, scope, moderation, questions

Some websites, [Tunebat](https://tunebat.com) as one, are exceptional in showing you details like a pieces Key, BPM and danceability. Sometimes, however, a piece is not on there. Research concluded first, are we then permitted to ask the tonal centre on here?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest asking the question in chat.

- It circumvents any issue of being on or off topic.
- It would be really nice to see a more active chat room.
- Personally, I don't feel this kind of question is a good fit for the main site, but I enjoy answering them, so would be a likely answerer in a chat discussion.
- Should enough of these pop up in chats, then a good case could be made for making them on topic for the main site.